# Inexistent PHP file successfully required and run?

Tags: php

I make tests on localhost (Windows, WAMP Server) so never bothered to test my code again after pushing them to remote server (Linux) which, after a few days, is giving this error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

So I looked into it and found something.

Here is the crime scene and my detective work on localhost:

```
echo $initEntityAutoFile;
if (file_exists($initEntityAutoFile)) {
    echo ' - EXISTS - ';
} else {
    echo ' - NOT - ';
}
$initEntityAuto = require $initEntityAutoFile; // the line giving the error
echo get_class($initEntityAuto);
echo PHP_EOL, get_include_path();
```

Which gives this:

```
/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php - NOT - Closure
.;C:\php\pear
```

Seems I'm requiring this path: `/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php` which is a relative path immediately under my project document root. No wonder my remote server doesn't find the file since it's not an absolute path at all. It should be `/home/xxx/public_html/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php` or `C:/project/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php`.

But the weird thing is, while the remote server gives an error on this, my localhost is correctly finding the file - with **file_exists**() returning **FALSE** but `$initEntityAuto` successfully getting the content, a **closure** in that file. Neither does the `require` raise any error, otherwise I would have found the problem and fixed it.

This is really weird. Why?

I could just correct the path and get on but this is kind of haunting me. If anybody can give an answer, I would sleep better.

===========

Additional info:

1. The `require` line is in a function in a file that's very deep down the project directories, so it's not in the same directory as `/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php`.
2. `$initEntityAutoFile`, a.k.a. the path string `/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php` is passed in the function as a parameter.

Comment: what does `getcwd()` return right before require call on localhost? What are the folders there in the folder returned by `getwcd()` before require call on localhost? What is the full path to the file being actually returned by successful `require()` on localhost?

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for the tip. It helped me find the culprit. I'll layout what I find in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Alexey, I used getcwd() to find what the current working directory is before the `require` line:

> - localhost: **X:\my_project**
> - remote server: **/home/xxx/public_html**

Now that I'm requiring this path: `/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php` (with a **beginning slash**), on my localhost (Windows, WAMP Server), the path is automatically translated to absolute path:

```
X:\my_project/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php
```

So my code works properly on localhost.

However on the remote server (Linux), when I'm requiring the path `/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php`, the file system treats it as an absolute path instead of concatenating it to the current working directory because it has a **beginning slash**:

```
/cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php
```

Therefore causing the "*failed to open stream: No such file or directory*" error.

Eventually, we have 2 solutions:

1. Use absolute path on both localhost and remote server.
2. Use **cli/aaa/bbb/ccc.php** that is **without the beginning slash** so both localhost and remote server would correctly treat it as a relative path and concatenate it to the current working directory to get the right path.

Comment: That's what I suspected too. According to the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) "starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems" it you started it with "\" on Win machine or used `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant looks like it would not have found it either. As for your 2 solutions, I'd definitely go only with #1. What I usually do is `define('BASEPATH',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)))`  in the first lines of index/entry point project file, and use everywhere and then concatenate it with relative paths which will always result in absolute path